# TortoiseHg Workbench Mercurial: Update to old version without creating new branch

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have the following versions

```
v 3
v 2
v 1
```

I want to create a new version, v 4, that looks exactly like v 2. I do not want to create a new branch.

I have tried:

Right-click v 2 and then "browse at revision" and then 'revert to revision' and 'revert all file'. Committing this does create v 4 looking like v 2, but it also creates duplicate '.orig' copies of all the files, which are a bother to delete.

Right-click v 2: "Update". This creates a new branch, which I do not want. This used to work without creating a new branch, but it now longer does and I don't know what is different.

EDIT: there can be any number of version between the one that I want to copy and the latest version.

Comment: Do you want to keep 3, or is it trash that you can get rid of permanently?

Comment: I don't see 'revert to revision' making .orig files unless the files aren't clean.

Answer (score 1):

Backout v.3:

Select this changeset in CSET-view - RClick - Backout

Comment: In my example there is only 1 version between the latest version and the one that I want to copy, but that is not necessarily the case. So then this wouldn't work?

Comment: @user984003 - backout every changeset inbetween

Comment: There are 10 or more. There must be a different way of going back to an old version.

Comment: Anonymous branching + dummy-merge

Answer (score 1):

```
hg update tip
hg revert -r V2 -C
hg commit -m deja vu
```